# Error Type of expression is ambiguous without more context when pulling from Firebase Document with specific ID, mapping to Codable

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a Codable struct called TheUser and im trying to get a firebase document to map to that and continue on with authentication. I can login to everything fine and when calling the fetchUser func it gives me this error. Note: I copied this code identically to the firebase documentation.

[image]

Here is the code for the func

```
    func fetchUser(uid: String) {
        db.collection("users").getDocument { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No User Profile Found")
                return
            }
            
            self.theuser = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> TheUser? in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: TheUser.self)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the entire ViewModel (ignore the // Im still debugging)

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: Firebase.User?
    @Published var didAuthenticateUser = false
    @Published var accountWasFound = false
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    @Published var theuser = [TheUser]()
    private var tempUserSession: Firebase.User?
    
    private let service = UserService()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
        
    init() {
        self.userSession = Auth.auth().currentUser
        //self.fetchUser()
    }
    
    func checkEmail(email: String) {
        Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: email, completion: {
                (e, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else if e != nil {
                    self.accountWasFound.toggle()
                    print("Account Was Found")
                }
            })
    }
    
    func login(withEmail email: String, password: String) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to sign in with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            self.userSession = user
            self.fetchUser(uid: self.userSession!.uid)
            //self.didAuthenticateUser.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchUser(uid: String) {
        db.collection("users").getDocument { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No User Profile Found")
                return
            }
            
            self.theuser = documents.compactMap { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> TheUser? in
                try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: TheUser.self)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func register(withEmail email: String, password: String, fullname: String, username: String) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("DEBUG: Failed to register with error \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            self.tempUserSession = user
            
            let data = ["email": email,
                        "username": username.lowercased(),
                        "fullname": fullname,
                        "uid": user.uid]
            
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .setData(data) { _ in
                    self.didAuthenticateUser = true
                }
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        // sets user session to nil so we show login view
        userSession = nil
        
        // signs user out on server
        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    
    /*
    func uploadProfileImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        guard let uid = tempUserSession?.uid else { return }
        
        ImageUploader.uploadImage(image: image) { profilePictureUrl in
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                .document(uid)
                .updateData(["profilePictureUrl": profilePictureUrl]) { _ in
                    self.userSession = self.tempUserSession
                    self.fetchUser()
                }
        }
    }
    
    func persistImageToStorage() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "/profile_image/profile_\(uid)")
        guard let imageData = self.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
            if let err = err {
                self.StatusMessage = "Failed to push image to Storage: \(err)"
                return
            }
            
            ref.downloadURL { url, err in
                if let err = err {
                    self.StatusMessage = "Failed to retrieve downloadURL: \(err)"
                    return
                }
                self.profilePictureURL = url?.absoluteString ?? ""
                self.StatusMessage = "Successfully stored image with url: \(url?.absoluteString ?? "")"
                Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                    .document(self.userSession?.uid ?? "")
                    .updateData(["profilePictureURL": self.profilePictureURL]) { _ in
                        print("Uploaded Profile Picture")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func bannerImageToStorage() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "/profile_image/header_\(uid)")
        guard let imageData = self.headerImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) else { return }
        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, err in
            if let err = err {
                self.StatusMessage = "Failed to push image to Storage: \(err)"
                return
            }
            
            ref.downloadURL { url, err in
                if let err = err {
                    self.StatusMessage = "Failed to retrieve downloadURL: \(err)"
                    return
                }
                self.headerImageURL = url?.absoluteString ?? ""
                self.StatusMessage = "Successfully stored image with url: \(url?.absoluteString ?? "")"
                Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
                    .document(self.userSession?.uid ?? "")
                    .updateData(["headerPhotoURL": self.headerImageURL]) { _ in
                        print("Banner Uploaded")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchUser() {
        guard let uid = self.userSession?.uid else { return }
        
        service.fetchUser(withUid: uid) { user in
            self.currentUser = user
        }
    }
     */
}
```

And here is the code for the Codable struct

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct TheUser: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var username: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var fullname: String
    var profilePictureURL: String
    var email: String
    var isVerified: Int
    var followers: Int
    var isCurrentUser: Bool
}
```

I am expecting this to run when called, fetch the data and then login the user. The app will then pull from the viewmodel.theuser to full in UI elements on the page and in the app.

Comment: If you option-click the documents variable, what type does the pop-up help say it is?

Comment: *I copied this code identically to the firebase documentation* - well no, it's not identical. Your function may have been intended to get a single user as the user `uid` is passed, along with `getDocument` which would get a single document. However, the `uid` is ignored and then the code maps over all of the retrieved users. So - the code and question is ambiguous; do you want to get a single user via their `uid` or get ALL of the users and do something with those? If it's a single user, use `getDocument` like this `db.collection("users").document(uid).getDocument {`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is implying the compiler can't infer the type of `documents`.  It's been a while since I've played with Firestore, but iirc correctly getting a snapshot requires the `getDocuments` (i.e. the plural) method, not the singular `getDocument`.

Using the `getDocument` API call will lead to the the completion handler taking `document, error` as it's input, not `querySnapshot, error`, which probably explains why the compiler can't computer what is effectively a type of `document.documents`.

Change the method call to

```
db.collection("users").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in //...
```

and see if the compiler is happier.

Note: all from memory, as I don't have a firestore project/database handy to test with...

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this didn't seem to fix the issue. Appreciate the response  non the less! Im very confused